# Where should the logic of toggling the visibility of the view resides in in Model-View-Presenter in Android, Presenter or Activity?

Tags: android, mvp

I am developing an Android application using Kotlin programming language. I am starting to use the Model-View-Presenter pattern for my application. To be honest, this is my first time using the MVP pattern even though I have been doing Android Development quite a little while. Now, I am a little bit struggling following the best practices and standards of the pattern.

This is the feature now I am currently developing. A very simple and basic feature.

The application will update a text view. When the text view is updated, a string (message) will be passed to a function as a parameter. Inside the function, if the string is empty, it will hide the text view. Otherwise, it will show the text view again. My struggle is that I am not quite sure how to implement my code that fits the MVP pattern. Especially, the logic to toggle the visibility state of the text view.

This is the current signature of my presenter class called, LoginActivityPresenter

```
class LoginActivityPresenter(viewArg: View)
{
    private var view:View = viewArg

    interface View
    {
        fun updateErrorMessageTextView(message: String)
    }
}
```

What I am thinking is that the activity class will implement the LoginActivityPresenter.View and provide the implementation of the updateErrorMessageTextView method. So in the activity, inside one single function, it will do the following tasks.

It will check if the string is empty. If yes, it will hide the view. Otherwise, it will show the view (back). Then it will set the text view with the message. All in the activity class because of the above presenter class signature.

The other way I am thinking of implementing LoginActivityPresenter class is as follows.

```
class LoginActivityPresenter(viewArg: View)
{
    private var view:View = viewArg

    fun updateErrorMessage(message: String) {
        if (message.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            this.view.hideErrorTextView()
            return
        }

        this.view.showErrorTextView()
        this.view.updateErrorMessageTextView(message)
    }

    interface View
    {
        fun updateErrorMessageTextView(message: String)

        fun showErrorTextView()

        fun hideErrorTextView()
    }
}
```

So in the second implementation, the presenter class will handle the logic of showing or hiding the view based on the string value rather than logic is being handled by the activity class.

My question is that which approach is more suitable and standard way for the MVP pattern and why?

Comment: I think of last one being ideal. if you change toggle logic or condition, you have to change presenter. because there is no change in view.

Comment: Cheers @Choim. That makes sense.

Comment: Hi @Choim thanks for the previous comment. What about the logic of starting the new activity? Should it reside in the activity/ fragment class or should it be in the presenter class?

Comment: same things. `view` just know that it should start activity. but it doesn't know why it should start activity.